# Can't resolve 'fs' in 'node_modules/dotenv/lib'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm ***not* using create-react-app**

I tried putting this at the top of my **React component**'s `tsx` file:

```
require('dotenv/config');
const slackUrl = process.env.JOIN_URL;
```

**And I get:**
`Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'node_modules/dotenv/lib' at webpackMissingModule`

I've installed `dotenv` via `package.json`, so not sure what else I need to resolve this.

I'm running the site locally with **webpack**.

This also did not work, same error:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(`process.env.JOIN_URL: ${process.env.JOIN_URL}`);
const slackUrl = process.env.JOIN_URL;
```

I also put this in my package.json, but didn't make any difference:

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false
},
```